# Flyway spring boot app doesn't apply insert script upon starting

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

I have a spring-boot JPA app that I am trying to integrate flyway with. My app starts fine and it runs the create schema(V1_somescript.sql) in my local DB, but it doesn't run or apply the insert(V2_insert_script.sql) script. Here is what my configuration looks like:

pom.xml for flyway:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

application.properties file:

```
# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE / FLYWAY
# ===============================

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.flyway.check-location=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

# ===============================
# DataSource
# ===============================
spring.flyway.locations=classpath*:resources/db/migrations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:3306/my_schema?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
```

Here is the V1_create_schema.sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE `lang` (
  `lang` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the V2_insert_schema.sql script:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `lang`(`lang`, `name`)
VALUES  ('ar-AE', 'Arabic'),
  ('cs-CZ', 'Czech'),
  ('da-DK', 'Danish'),
  ('de-DE', 'German'),
  ('el-GR', 'Greek'),
  ('en-GB', 'English (UK)'),
  ('en-US', 'English (US)');
```

Also, here is the bean definition in my AppConfig.java:

```
  @Bean
  @Profile(value = {"default", "memory"})
  public Flyway flyway(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    Flyway flyway =
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(
                dataSourceProperties.getUrl(),
                dataSourceProperties.getUsername(),
                dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .baselineOnMigrate(true)
            .locations("classpath:db/migration")
            .load();
    return flyway;
  }
```

I don't get any error on starting the app on my IDE. I dropped the schema and created the schema before starting the app, and saw that app started fine and applied the create schema, but the **lang** table did not have any records in it.

Also, the application logs seem to suggest that it may not have applied the V1_create_schema.sql migrations via flyway and instead, it must be done by hibernate. Anyone know what could I be missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like Hibernate creates the data model for you (`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`), which you can disable since you are using Flyway.

Anyway when using Flyway on an existing non-empty schema you want to

```
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true
```

to ensure the Flyway History table is created when it first runs.

Comment: So I just added that, but still no change in the outcome. :(

Comment: You can add `spring.flyway.enabled=true` (although this is the default) and maybe change `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration` (maybe it doesnt find the migration files)

Comment: yes. That was it. I think the classpath couldn't find the migration files since it had `resources/db/migration` in my config settings. Removing `resources` worked.